# How do i check if the bool is false or true and then do something?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public void globalPb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
            {
                if (pause == false)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        pbs[i].PauseAnimate();
                        pause = true;
                    }
                }
                if (pause == true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        pbs[i].ContinueAnimate();
                    }
                    pause = false;
                }

            }
        }
```

I want that if the variable pause is false then pause and if its true then continue.
But in the IF that check if its false i set it to true so next its checking if its true so it will never pause.

Howq should i do it the logic of the checking ?

Comment: You can just use `else if` instead of `if`.

Comment: And when it comes to a plain old boolean, you can use `else` instead of `else if`.

Comment: If you want to pause when `pause` is false and continue when `pause` is true, you might consider renaming it to `active` or `animating`, or even `unpaused`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `else` part of the statement:

```
if (!pause) {
  for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++) {
    pbs[i].PauseAnimate();
  }
  pause = true;
} else {
  for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++) {
    pbs[i].ContinueAnimate();
  }
  pause = false;
}
```

To clean it up further, I would probably write the true part first:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; ++i) {
  if (paused) {
    pbs[i].ContinueAnimate();
  } else {
    pbs[i].PauseAnimate();
  }
}
pause = !pause;
```

Comment: It won't execute the `else` if the `if` is satisfied.

Comment: I would swap the `if` and the `else` around because `if (pause)` is easier to read than `if (!pause)`.

Comment: you can just flip pause outside of the if/else statement afterwards

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `if (pause == false)`, you can do `if (!pause)`, and you can also do `if ... else ...`, so you now get:

```
if (pause)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
  {
    pbs[i].ContinueAnimate();
  }
  pause = false;
}
else
{
  for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
  {
    pbs[i].PauseAnimate();
  }      
  pause = true;
}
```

Note that I rearranged it to do `if (pause) ... else ...`, which is a bit more intuitive than `if (!pause) ... else ...`. I also rearranged your for loops slightly so they look the same - this could even lead you to a fully refactored solution:

```
public void globalPb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
    {
      AnimatePauseOrContinue(pause, pbs[i]);
    }
    pause = !pause;
  }
}
public void AnimatePauseOrContinue(bool shouldPause, pbType pb)
{
  if (shouldPause)
    pb.PauseAnimate();
  else
    pb.ContinueAnimate();
}
```